# Just Another Who am I Riddle

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking

> I am a ruler high and mighty
>
> I am not a fan of perfumery
>
> Though I love my jewelry
>
> So who am I?

This is my first riddle and I appreciate any feedback.

Comment: I was thinking a ruler

Comment: Or put it on https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/ with cards too

Comment: @Duck isn't lateral thinking tag for things like these or am I mistaken

Comment: Oh, I was just saying you could

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you be

> The King/Queen of Diamonds?

I am a ruler high and mighty

> The king/queen is royalty.

I am not a fan of perfumery

> Cards have nothing to do with smell.

Though I love my jewelry

> Diamonds

Comment: Correct! And this fast. I will accept this as soon as I can (10 minutes?) I planned perfumery as both a rhyme and as a way to distinguish Queen and King. Oh by the way I actually wanted ask you something if you have the time.

Comment: I suspected that regarding perfumery, but I didn't want to impose any gender stereotypes. :) What did you want to ask me?

Comment: I checked your questions and answers and they are certainly impressive.I wanted to know how long you have been solving puzzles and riddles, how you got this good and were you always this good. Plus maybe a few more questions later.

Comment: @user500668 Thank you. It mostly just comes from a lot of practice. I never really started with a goal of getting better at puzzles/riddles, it's just a fun thing to do on the side that I improve over time. I wish you good luck in your puzzling endeavors, and hopefully you become a more active user on this site. :)

Comment: oh I may be bothering you but two more things. One is about one of your answers, namely the one with the chained inequality that is also seen in your profile. (the one with poker hands) what exactly was you thought process on that? how did you came up with the solution?  and the other one is https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/51087/a-simple-scientific-test/69304#69304 this question, for the life of me I can't figure this out. maybe you can? and oh last thing, how frequently do you get stuck and what do you do when you get stuck?

Comment: @user500668 For the first question, it took me several minutes, but I got it through noticing patterns. I noticed that each of the numbers had five digits and that there were many repeat digits. After some thinking, poker hands came to mind. For the second question, I have no idea. Maybe I'll think about it later. I get stuck all the time. Some riddles just require some guesswork. But for others, noticing patterns and making a lot of small observations can help with the thinking process.